# Notation for polynomials of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, notation

Let $q(x) = x^2$ and $p(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 = q(x) + q(y)$. Then, I can write $p \in \mathbb{R}[x, y]$, but I would like to write something like $p \in \mathbb{R}[q(x), q(y)]$. Is such a thing valid notation? And if it is, does it change the definition of $p$, i.e., would then $p(x, y) = x + y$?

Comment: I would think that to say that $p\in k[q(x),q(y)]$ would mean that there was $P\in k[x,y]$ such that $p=P(q(x),q(y)]$. In this formalization, $p(x,y)$ would be $p$ itself.

Comment: @Lubin When you say "$p(x, y)$ would be $p$ itself", you mean $p(x, y) = q(x) + q(y)$ and not $p(x, y) = x + y$, don't you?

Comment: For that example, yes. The $x+y$ would be your $P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $q(x) = x^2$. Then you can write $\mathbb{R}[q(x), q(y)]=\mathbb{R}[x^2, y^2]$, and this would mean the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ in which only even powers of $x$ and $y$ appear.

Then $p(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 \in\mathbb{R}[x^2, y^2]$ since the only powers of $x$ and $y$ which appear in $p$ are even.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\mathbb{R}[q(x), q(y)]$ is always posible if you fixe the polynomial $q(x)$ but what you get is a (strict) subset of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ (in fact well structured, is it a subring?). With this you discard infinitely many polynomials of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. Anyway your notation could be useful for certain particular goals.